# Conditional statement with Expression Language

Tags: el, xpages

I'm trying to do a conditional statement with Expression Language, but can't get it to work. According to JSF 2.0 documentation it's possible, but as XPages is on JSF 1.2 I don't know if it's supported.

Basically this is the code:

```
<xp:text
   escape="true"
   id="computedField1">
   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{(repeatLine.columnvalue >= 1) ? 'a' : 'b'}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

The compiler gives an error "Error in value syntax, property 'value'". The problem is the same if I convert the "xp:this.value" to an attribute in the "xp:text" tag.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Update: this now works in the DDE 9 beta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it, but you have to use it with the $ instead of the # operator, at least I haven't been able to make it work with it.

Comment: That's a shame, as I'm trying to use it inside a repeater. But you're right, it removes the compile error.

Comment: you probably know this, but you always have the option to use SSJS in that context do it as well.